# Ignore fields from yaml when parsing it using SnakeYaml (Unable to find property on class)

Tags: parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using SnakeYaml to parse yaml file, is there anyway to ignore properities from the yaml file ?

Answer (score 39):

I found it :)

```java
    Representer representer = new Representer();
    representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);
    
    
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(MyClass.class),representer);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you have a custom `PropertyUtils` that call `super.getProperty(type, name)`. In this case you need to wrap the call in a `try-catch` block and return an empty `Property` object if it fails (:

Answer (score 3):

This is based on the solution from **Bilal**; however, the empty Representer Constructor has been marked as deprecated.

Adding the following will avoid using the deprecated constructor.

### For SnakeYml 1.x

```
  Representer representer = new Representer(new DumperOptions());
  representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);
  Constructor constructor = new Constructor(MyClass.class);
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor, representer);
```

### For SnakeYml >= 2.x

```
  Representer representer = new Representer(new DumperOptions());
  representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);
  LoaderOptions loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions();
  Constructor constructor = new Constructor(MyClass.class, loaderOptions);
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor, representer);
```